# Using javascript to make one field required or other not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

HI I am trying to use the following javascript to make mobile or landline mandory i am using .net webforms and I have the following script but its not working i have given my controls the required client ids and loading the script between script tags at bottom other script on the page is firing fine so no its not my page at problem but this script.

I am attaching my controls the following way to the scripts

```
   <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s, e) { OnLandLineValdiate(s, e); }" ValueChanged="function(s, e) {   OnUpdateControlValue(s, e); }" />
```

Which are correct way according to the control suite i am using

```
function OnLandLineValidate(s,e)     {
     if (!e.isValid)
        return;

      var landLine = landLineEdit.GetValue();
      e.isValid = mobileEdit == null || landLine == null;
      e.errorText = "Land Line or Mobile is required."

 }


function OnMobileValidate(s, e) {
 if (!e.isValid)
            return;
        var mobileEdit = mobileEdit.GetValue();

        e.isValid = mobileEdit == null || landLine == null;
        e.errorText = "Land Line or Mobile is required."

 }
```

What i want to happen is if mobile is filled in then the two conditions are met if landline is filled in then the two condtions are also met ?.

Comment: You should fix the typos: I think it should be Validate, and no Valdiate, and in the second function, you wrote  `landLine == null` twice...

Comment: The second function does not have landine==null twice

Comment: jQuery is always the answer

Comment: The project is long going not allowed to change i am afraid @RaisingAgent

Comment: Well, "dont change it, if it's atleast partially running" - EA Games

Comment: on this line: var mobileEdit = mobileEdit.GetValue(); try renaming your var because it looks like the name is same as the ClientInstanceName of the mobileEdit control. Later you check for it to be not null but what instance: local var not null or client instance name of the mobileEdit is not null?. Also, landLine in the OnMobileValidate() is not defined at all. Is it a global var?

Answer (score 0):

Both are negative condition hence you should use **!=** operator instead of **==** operator.

```
e.isValid =(!(mobile == null && landline == null))
```